# How to covert the List of Models (Job) to Map<Long, Job>; based on a condition in Lambda

Tags: lambda, java-8

How covert the List jobs to Map jobMap; based on a condition.

The condition is, job.getParentId() == null

Below line converts all the list of jobs to map, but i need to have above mentioned condition.

```
Map<Long, String> parentJobs = jobs.stream().collect(
           Collectors.toMap(JobLog::getId, JobLog::getName));
```

below is the snippet of Job model.

```
class Job{
 Long id;
 String name;
 Long parentJob;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean a `filter`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just filter the stream before collecting.

```
Map<Long, String> parentJobs = jobs.stream()
    .filter(job -> job.getParentId() == null)
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(JobLog::getId, JobLog::getName));
```